# Enum on model being loaded twice after upgrade to Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums, ruby-on-rails-7, rails-upgrade

I've just upgraded to Rails 7, and suddenly I'm having a very odd issue with one of my models.

This is the model (please ignore the terrible naming of the keys and the fact that this would probably be better-suited as a boolean – it's legacy code ):

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord

  FIREARM_NAMES = %w{ Frame Pistol Receiver Revolver Rifle Shotgun }
  PAGINATE_BY   = 24

  enum map_price_source: [:map_source_is_distributor, :map_source_is_brand]

  ...

end
```

And when I try to load the class in a Rails console (either by just calling `Product` or by instantiating it via `Product.last`), the following error message is thrown:

```
ArgumentError: You tried to define an enum named "map_price_source" on the model "Product", but this will generate a instance method "map_source_is_distributor?", which is already defined by another enum.
```

`map_price_source` is the only enum in the `Product` class so `map_source_is_distributor` can't be used by two different enums in `Product`. And, in fact, that enum value is unique across the entire application.

Furthermore, I'm getting some warnings in console as well:

```
.../app/models/product.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant Product::FIREARM_NAMES
.../app/models/product.rb:3: warning: previous definition of FIREARM_NAMES was here
.../app/models/product.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant Product::PAGINATE_BY
.../app/models/product.rb:4: warning: previous definition of PAGINATE_BY was here
```

The error and the warnings seem to indicate that the `Product` class is somehow being loaded more than once. And even more odd, as far as I can tell this is the only class that this is happening for.

If anyone has any clue what could be causing this, I'd be extremely grateful.

Comment: are you doing something like `require 'product'` anywhere? one thing you can try is to put a debugger/byebug/binding.pry call at the beginning of the class and when it stops there you can check the stack to see if something looks off too

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).

There was a separate issue where we were using `decorate_attribute_type`, which was [removed in Rails 7](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39929). Once I updated that functionality to no longer use `decorate_attribute_type`, the "double load" errors stopped occurring.